# Remove dups after multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are multiple tables:

items → items_roles → roles

items → zones →  roles_zones → roles

```
items: id, zone_id
items_roles: role_id, item_id
zones: id
roles_zones: role_id, zone_id
roles: id, role_type_id,
```

I am trying to add role fields to items, it should take role_type and it is value from items_zones anf if it is NULL fetch fallback value from item zone (roles_zones).

I created this query:

```
SELECT
    items.id,
    z_roles.role_type_id as z_role_type_id, z_roles.id as z_role_id,
    i_roles.role_type_id as i_role_type_id, i_roles.id as i_role_id
  FROM items

  LEFT JOIN zones as j_zones ON j_zones.id = items.zone_id
  LEFT JOIN roles_zones ON roles_zones.zone_id = j_zones.id
  LEFT JOIN roles as z_roles ON (z_roles.id = roles_zones.role_id)

  LEFT JOIN items_roles ON items_roles.item_id = items.id
  LEFT JOIN roles as i_roles ON items_roles.role_id = i_roles.id
  AND (z_roles.role_type_id = i_roles.role_type_id)

  WHERE items.id = 834

  ORDER BY i_roles.id;
```

As result I see this:

```
id  | z_role_type_id | z_role_id | i_role_type_id | i_role_id 
-----+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
 834 |              5 |       111 |              5 |        68
 834 |             11 |       120 |             11 |       120
 834 |              7 |        77 |                |          
 834 |             12 |        91 |                |          
 834 |              4 |        78 |                |          
 834 |              2 |         2 |                |          
 834 |              5 |       111 |                |          
 834 |              8 |        36 |                |          
 834 |              8 |        36 |                |          
 834 |             12 |        91 |                |          
 834 |              4 |        78 |                |          
 834 |              2 |         2 |                |          
 834 |             11 |       120 |                |          
 834 |              7 |        77 |                |          
(14 rows)
```

There are 14 rows and I need only 7.

For example two rows:

```
id  | z_role_type_id | z_role_id | i_role_type_id | i_role_id
834 |              5 |       111 |              5 |        68
834 |              5 |       111 |                |
```

I want to remove rows with empty `i_role_type_id` and `i_role_id` if there are already row with these values.

This is desired output:

```
id  | z_role_type_id | z_role_id | i_role_type_id | i_role_id 
-----+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
 834 |              5 |       111 |              5 |        68
 834 |             11 |       120 |             11 |       120
 834 |              7 |        77 |                |          
 834 |             12 |        91 |                |          
 834 |              4 |        78 |                |          
 834 |              2 |         2 |                |         
 834 |              8 |        36 |                |          
(7 rows)
```

How do I rewrite a query?

**Now it works:**

```
SELECT items.id
  ,z_roles.role_type_id as z_role_type_id
  ,z_roles.id as z_role_id
  ,MAX(i_roles.role_type_id) as i_role_type_id
  ,MAX(i_roles.id) as i_role_id
FROM items

LEFT JOIN zones as j_zones ON j_zones.id = items.zone_id
LEFT JOIN roles_zones ON roles_zones.zone_id = j_zones.id
LEFT JOIN roles as z_roles ON (z_roles.id = roles_zones.role_id)

LEFT JOIN items_roles ON items_roles.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN roles as i_roles ON items_roles.role_id = i_roles.id
AND (z_roles.role_type_id = i_roles.role_type_id)

WHERE items.id = 834
Group By items.id, z_roles.role_type_id, z_roles.id
ORDER BY items.id, i_role_id;
```

Result:

```
 id  | z_role_type_id | z_role_id | i_role_type_id | i_role_id 
-----+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
 834 |              5 |       111 |              5 |        68
 834 |             11 |       120 |             11 |       120
 834 |              7 |        77 |                |          
 834 |              2 |         2 |                |          
 834 |             12 |        91 |                |          
 834 |              4 |        78 |                |          
 834 |              8 |        36 |                |          
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need is a simple **Group By** in your select statement to aggregate the data.

> Group By items.id, z_roles.role_type_id, z_roles.id

Specifically;

```
 SELECT items.id
  ,z_roles.role_type_id as z_role_type_id
  ,z_roles.id as z_role_id
  ,MAX(i_roles.role_type_id) as i_role_type_id
  ,MAX(i_roles.id) as i_role_id
FROM items

LEFT JOIN zones as j_zones ON j_zones.id = items.zone_id
LEFT JOIN roles_zones ON roles_zones.zone_id = j_zones.id
LEFT JOIN roles as z_roles ON (z_roles.id = roles_zones.role_id)

LEFT JOIN items_roles ON items_roles.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN roles as i_roles ON items_roles.role_id = i_roles.id
AND (z_roles.role_type_id = i_roles.role_type_id)

WHERE items.id = 834
Group By items.id, z_roles.role_type_id, z_roles.id
ORDER BY i_roles.id;
```

Comment: `ERROR:  column "i_roles.id" must appear in the GROUP BY`

If add this `i_roles.id` to GROUP BY it returns 9 rows (2 dups).

Comment: Please reconfirm. Note that the error expects column **"i_roles.id"** included in either an aggregate function, or the group by clause - but it is included in an aggregate function (*max()*).

Comment: Just a typo, it works with `ORDER BY i_role_id;`. Thank you very much! You saved my day.

Can I ask you advise on some good sql book, please? I feel I am doing cargo cult stuff with sql sometimes.

Comment: glad it helped. 
lol @ *cargo cult*...
check out [T-SQL Fundamentals] (https://www.amazon.com/T-SQL-Fundamentals-Itzik-Ben-Gan-ebook/dp/B01J89I7PI). 
Although it's written based-on microsoft's flavour (T-SQL), you can use it for getting started in just about any flavour. Be sure to complete the labs and exercises at the end of each chapter.